# Integrating this gamma kernel-like function

Tags: integration, gamma-function, gamma-distribution

I am trying to integrate the following function:

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)^{a-1} \exp\Big(-\frac{b}{x}\Big)dx \tag{1}
$$

The [blog post](https://michaellindon.github.io/lindonslog/mathematics/statistics/marginal-likelihood-model-evidence-bayesian-regression/) I am reading claims the answer is

$$
\frac{\Gamma(a)}{b^a}. \tag{2}
$$

The author suggests that we can solve $(1)$ by observing that it is a "gamma kernel" (second to last equation in the post). I assume he means the gamma function without the normalization. However, that *doesn't* look quite like either a gamma or inverse–gamma kernel. The form is slightly different. This is what I tried instead:

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)^{a-1} \exp\Big(-\frac{b}{x}\Big)dx
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 \Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)^{a+1} \exp\Big(-\frac{b}{x}\Big)dx
\\
&= \mathbb{E}[X^2] \frac{\Gamma(a)}{b^a}
\\
&= \frac{b^2}{(a-1)(a-2)} \frac{\Gamma(a)}{b^a}.
\end{align} \tag{3}
$$

In other words, I convert the desired integral into an unnormalized second moment, which I have a closed form solution for.

Who is correct? If I am wrong, where is my mistake and how can I correctly arrive at $(2)$ from $(1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a change of variable $t=b/x$ and assuming that $b>0$ we have that
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty }x^{1-a}e^{-b/x}\,\mathrm d x=\int_0^{\infty } (b/t)^{1-a}e^{-t}bt^{-2}\,\mathrm d t\\
=b^{2-a}\int_{0}^{\infty }t^{a-3}e^{-t}\,\mathrm d t=\frac{\Gamma (a-2)}{b^{a-2}},\quad \text{  when }a>2
$$

what coincides with your result.